# Como deixar apto o geckodriver para uso do selenium?

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Em Python 3 e Ubuntu, eu quero executar um teste com selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

from time import sleep

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox')
ff = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
ff.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
print(ff.page_source)
```

Mas tenho essa mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1333, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browser.py", line 7, in <module>
    ff = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/live-de-python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Eu fui no site do geckodriver para fazer o download: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Baixei a última versão para Linux e digitei esses comandos no terminal:

```
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64.tar.gz
rm geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
```

O geckodriver.exe precisa agora ser copiado para /usr/local/bin, certo?

Eu tentei:

```
cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Mas tive acesso negado:

```
cp: não foi possível criar arquivo comum '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver': Permissão negada
```

Como posso copiar o geckodriver para /usr/local/bin?

Ou basta indicar o PATH do sistema? Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode mover o `geckodriver` pro /usr/local/bin com permissões de super usuário.

`sudo cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/`